# How do I simply kill a process from my batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, tasklist

My code needs to check if `notepad.exe` is listed under `tasklist`. If it is, the batch file will close it.

```
 @echo off
 tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" > nul
 if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "notepad.exe"
 exit
```

Comment: What specifically, is the issue with your provided code?

Comment: `@"%__AppDir__%tasklist.exe" /Fi "ImageName Eq notepad.exe" /Fo CSV | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /R "^\"notepad\.exe\"" 1> NUL && "%__AppDir__%taskkill.exe" /Im notepad.exe 1> NUL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tasklist` always returns an errorlevel of 0, even when it doesn't find anything. In order to work around this, you should instead pipe the output of `tasklist` to `find`, which will return an errorlevel of 0 if the process is found and 1 if the process is not found.

```
@echo off
tasklist | find /I "notepad.exe" >nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" taskkill /f /im "notepad.exe"
```

Comment: Whilst this will work, I'd still let `tasklist` filter for the desired image name for the sake of performance…